# make Chatiing page via SMS like in android inbox

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to develop an application that allows users to chat with each other via sms..

I created an activity that sends and receives sms, but I don't know how can I make their chatting moving up (as in SMS messages in iPhone or Android native inbox it seems like chatting page),

All I did is make the message in edit text and receives it in textview ... actually i don't know what's the name of this thing to make search ... can anyone inform me what's the name of this technique!!! and please give me some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Simply Create One Screen with one layout which has one ListView And At bottom of screen One edittText

### Screen

ListView

---

### EditText  and   Send Sms Button Here

When you send sms Add That sms To your list Adpater and display on screen
And when your receive sms add that sms content to your adapter and notify your list

Comment: are you sure ? ListView will Solve my problem? do you hava any tutorial?please?

Comment: is it listView or array list? i am little confused

Comment: Manage your Arraylist with incoming and outgoing sms and set in adapter of listview and notify listview

Comment: PLEASE I AM REALLY STUCK HERE!